# import _socket: "Import Error: DLL load failed"

Tags: python, python-2.7, reinstall

I was attempting to install Django and pymc yesterday.  After running into a lot of problems I decided to just re-install Python 2.7.  I've done that but am now having problems import almost anything.  I get a bunch of lines, the last of which are:

```
 File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 71, in <module>
   import socket
 File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
   import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Whether I run python in the command prompt (which works) and try to do `import pip`, or type outside of the shell `python get-pip.py` I get those same last lines.

I should state for the record that I have two versions of python on my machine, one being 2.7, and the other being I THINK 2.6 located in a canopy folder, but that doesn't work either, giving an error message of `ImportError: No module named os".  I have my PATH environment variable leading with "c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts".

I've re-installed python a couple times now, and have tried the repair option as well, but to no avail.  Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  It seems that when I uninstalled Python, I neglected to delete the C:\Python27 folder.  I uninstalled again, deleted the folder, then reinstalled and it works now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `_socket.pyd` in your python27\DLLs directory?  Can you run python.exe directly, then attempt to `import _socket`?  If that works, what does `_socket.__file__` contain?

Comment: Yes, `_socket.pyd` is in C:\Python27\DLLs.  Running python and trying to `import _socket` gets me the same ImportError as before.

Comment: How did you install python?

Comment: Just went to python.org, Downloads, "Download Python 2.7.7", and used the installer.

Comment: Get some tool, e.g. `depends32.exe` and check what's wrong with your python installation.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the MSVCR dlls? For python27 is this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error afters upgrading to python 2.7.12.

To solve it, I did another install into the same directory. Interestingly enough, the installer did not recognize the existing installation. I made sure to check "add python.exe to Path". After that, it worked.

Attempting to install python 2.7.12 again, the installer recognized the existing installation and offered me change/repair/uninstall options.

Update:
In retrospective, the reason might have been, that I unintentionally mixed a 32-bit installation with a 64-bit update (or vice versa). Python doesn't seem to install into different directories or use different DLL-names. The installer doesn't warn you either. So after the update, your DLLs are a unhealthy mix of 32 and 64-bit variants.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, after I mix py2 & py3 enviroment(windows 10), sovled it by:

```
1. Uninstall all py2 & py3
2. install py 2.7.14 win32 (now newest)
3. add following enviroment varaible to system Path & PythonPath:
1) C:\Python27
2) C:\Python27\Script
3) C:\Python27\Lib
4) C:\Python27\DLLs
```

ref:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902431/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-when-importing)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem by adding the following in the env variables:

```
PYTHONHOME : C:\Python39\apps\Python39
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("address where the socket module is present like C:\Python34\Lib\")
import socket
```

try this it might work

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest getting, PyWin32 or either PyWin64, depending on your System architecture. If your system is x86, get PyWin32, otherwise get PyWin64 if your system is x64. I have similar problems myself and getting PyWin32 helped me out in fixing these problems.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an issue with Python 2.7.13 as this moment. Installing 2.7.12 fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Actually its look like  import _socket calls is been failed which is causing this error 
ImportError: DLL load failed

The get-pip.py the function b85decode() is trying to import the _socket which is not found , 
The Solution to this is you can install any 3.X version and run the get-pip.py which should resolve the issue and get pip installed.

**C:\Python33>python.exe  C:\get-pip.py**

Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |################################| 1.1MB 197kB/s

Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-7.1.2 setuptools-18.5 wheel-0.26.0