# I install gdcm in windows ,then i "import gdcm" in python, I got anerror

Tags: python, windows, gdcm, pydicom

I install gdcm in windows ,then I "import gdcm" in python, I got this error,
My environment is python2.7.9, gdcm is GDCM-2.8.4-Windows-x86_64,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes, because Python 3 is recquired. You should upgrade your Python environment. If you need to stay with Python 2, maybe  [this question would be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297078/how-to-install-gdcm-python-wrapping-on-windows-system).